# Nginx remove leading slash and trailing file type suffix and pass to php

Tags: nginx

I have received to migrate an existing website written in old php hosted on Apache, and I will deploy to an Nginx.

I wish to have URL like this: http://example.com/about.html
To be executed like this http://example.com/content.php?page=about

So I need to remove leading slash and remove html.  The config below works if I hardcode a specific page:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /content.php?page=about;
}
```

But of  course it always serve about regardless if I access our-company.html, or our-services.html.  I am not sure what I need to replace the "about" string in the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `rewrite` directive to perform the actual translation. You can invoke it from a named `location` specified as the last parameter on the `try_files` statement.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)\.html$ /content.php?page=$1 last;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.